# JMockit : How to avoid code from superclasses' constructors

Tags: java, junit, hierarchy, jmockit

I need to test a class SportCar, which extends Car. The problem is that when I create my object under test

```
SportCar car = new SportCar();
```

it will also call the constructor from parent classes, for example, Car(). Those constructors do a lot of things, have a lot of environment dependencies and need a lot of configuration files I don't have, so I would like to create an instance of SportCar without calling inherited constructors.

The only solution I know for this is to create a Mockup for Car in which I overwrite constructor ($init) and static block ($clinit). But now my problem is, what happens if there are many classes in my hierarchy (SportCar extends Car that extends A that extends B that extends C...) and I want to avoid all the constructors? Should I create Mocks for ALL the previous classes?

```
class A extends B{
    public A(){
        // Plenty of things to avoid during tests
    }
}

class Car extends A{
    public Car(){
        // Plenty of things to avoid during tests
    }
}

class SportCar extends Car(){
}
```

Comment: If you want a class SportsCar that doesn't have all the baggage of the Car class, then don't have it inherit from Car, simple as that. I sense that Car shouldn't have been a class at all, but rather an interface.

Comment: Agreed with @Hovercraft in this case, inheritance is evil. Use composition instead, and implement interfaces. If you want "shared logic" for all your cars, pull it in a collaborator object that you inject into SportCar (and whichever other Car that needs it) - you can have multiple implementations of that collaborator object, which will achieve the same features you have with inheritance, but in a much cleaner way - and make testing a lot easier, which is usually a good indicator of good design.

Comment: It's old code I can't change, but anyway I didn't mean SportCar doesn't need the inherited code from Car's constructor. I just sais that I don't want to call this code DURING the test. I mean, SportCar needs to inherit the code from Car's constructor, but since I want an isolated (unit) test, I don't want to call many classes during the test. Anyway, I know the design is bad: having such things in the constructor. having so many dependencies...

Comment: "I know the design is bad" in particular, it makes it difficult to tests, as you see here. "It's old code I can't change": I've never come acrosss such a statement that was ever really true.

Comment: ne is using jmockit, and there is easier way to do this with it

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jmockit, you do not have to do anything at all,  as all the superclass constructors are mocked by default.  In you unit test method you can just do:

```
public void testMockedStuff(@Mocked final ClassToBeMocked instance) {
```

to have evrything mocked away for you.  You do not even have to create instances yourself. 
Then you can modify annotation parameters to exclude methods you are teting from mocking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a protected "do nothing" constructor in `Car` and have a protected constructor in `SportsCar` that calls it and call that from your test class, which *can* see that constructor btw - it has the privileges to do so.

This could be considered a slight stretch of the "design for test" pattern.

Comment: Creating special constructors in your classes just for testing purposes is plain wrong imo. A better approach would be to call a certain method from the Car constructor, create a subclass for the SportsCar class and override the method containing all the load-steps.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I know there're better ways to do it to avoid this horrible situation by refactoring our code, but it's this kind of huge project whith old code and without Unit Tests, so I'm expected to create the Unit Test but not to change the code under test :( My question was more about JMockit... in terms of design I would also prefer to have a different scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the parent constructor using [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior)

```
suppress(constructor(EvilParent.class));
```

However, if you have to do a lot of unit tests it may be worth figuring out how to fake out the enironment as well.  Or convince other developers to let you do a little refactoring to allow service injection at least.

Comment: +1 for "convince other developers". But I'm incredulous that a mocking framework provides functionality for doing this.

Comment: I've never used this feature myself, but PowerMock uses a custom classloader to manipulate the bytecode itself to allow static methods to be mocked.

Comment: I've found PowerMock bytecode manipulation to cause unexpected complications at times. It's definitely powerful, but it has to be rather intrusive to be so.